# Catch close/refresh browser event and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a problem, i don't have to give the user the ability to refresh page because the data will be lost so what i did was block the refresh act using :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
  var message = "Why are you leaving?";
  e.returnValue = message;
  return message;
};
```

But when the user press reload I need to navigate to another page (don't allow the user to stay on the same page)

thank you

Comment: there's no difference between a reload an a navigate away. you could detect how you are navigating away with a click handler and supress this event.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i didn't understand how can i detect the navigation

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you please explain more? am stuck